# Develop Windows Desktop App On MacOs

Tags: c#, windows, macos, visual-studio

I have to develop a desktop app for windows in C# but currently i use a Mac. Is there any platform for Mac to support this as Visual Studio WPF does not support this at the moment.

Comment: Maybe this will help:  https://stormpath.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-using-visual-studio-on-a-mac

Comment: Virtual Machine might be an easy option.....